# How to use inverse kinematics on a finger (with rotation)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, inverse-kinematics

How to use inverse kinematics on a finger (with **rotation**)? Hi, I hope you can help me with this problem! I am trying to use the inverse kinematics of a finger, where I only know the rotation of the target (from a sensor) and another in the wrist, in this example I only have two bones (distal, middle), which I am guided by Dogzer example.

This is what my example does, but the inverse kinematics is being executed with respect to the *position*, and what I need is that it moves with respect to the **rotation** of the target 
[image: exampl]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[ExecuteInEditMode]

 public class InverseKinematics7 : MonoBehaviour {

  public Transform upperArm;
  public Transform forearm;
  public Transform hand;
  public Transform elbow;
  public Transform target;
  [Space(20)]
  public Vector3 uppperArm_OffsetRotation;
  public Vector3 forearm_OffsetRotation;
  public Vector3 hand_OffsetRotation;
  [Space(20)]
  public bool handMatchesTargetRotation = true;
  [Space(20)]
  public bool debug;

  float angle;
  float upperArm_Length;
  float forearm_Length;
  float arm_Length;
  float targetDistance;
  float adyacent;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {

  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void LateUpdate () {
      if(upperArm != null && forearm != null && hand != null && elbow != null && target != null){
          upperArm.LookAt (target, elbow.position - upperArm.position);
          upperArm.Rotate (uppperArm_OffsetRotation);

          Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross (elbow.position - upperArm.position, forearm.position - upperArm.position);



          upperArm_Length = Vector3.Distance (upperArm.position, forearm.position);
          forearm_Length =  Vector3.Distance (forearm.position, hand.position);
          arm_Length = upperArm_Length + forearm_Length;
          targetDistance = Vector3.Distance (upperArm.position, target.position);
          targetDistance = Mathf.Min (targetDistance, arm_Length - arm_Length * 0.001f);

          adyacent = ((upperArm_Length * upperArm_Length) - (forearm_Length * forearm_Length) + (targetDistance * targetDistance)) / (2*targetDistance);

          angle = Mathf.Acos (adyacent / upperArm_Length) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

          upperArm.RotateAround (upperArm.position, cross, -angle);

          forearm.LookAt(target, cross);
          forearm.Rotate (forearm_OffsetRotation);

          if(handMatchesTargetRotation){
              hand.rotation = target.rotation;
              hand.Rotate (hand_OffsetRotation);
          }

          if(debug){
              if (forearm != null && elbow != null) {
                  Debug.DrawLine (forearm.position, elbow.position, Color.blue);
              }

              if (upperArm != null && target != null) {
                  Debug.DrawLine (upperArm.position, target.position, Color.red);
              }
          }

      }

  }

  void OnDrawGizmos(){
      if (debug) {
          if(upperArm != null && elbow != null && hand != null && target != null && elbow != null){
              Gizmos.color = Color.gray;
              Gizmos.DrawLine (upperArm.position, forearm.position);
              Gizmos.DrawLine (forearm.position, hand.position);
              Gizmos.color = Color.red;
              Gizmos.DrawLine (upperArm.position, target.position);
              Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
              Gizmos.DrawLine (forearm.position, elbow.position);
          }
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: why aren't you applying the rotations to the corresponding joints?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: oh, sorry I misunderstood your example a little bit. I thought you had rotation values for all finger joints. But in your case, you could at least apply the rotation from your "target" IMU to the distal joint (represented in your example by the sphere between distal and middle bone). But I don't think that IK is the way to go for you since you don't have any positional tracking

Comment: I am using the IK to calculate the angles of the joints that exist between the fingers, the positioning is being calculated with other hardware

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't "Inverse Kinematics with rotation rather than position" essentially Forward Kinematics?